# Debugging generic functions in R

Tags: debugging, r

How do you debug a generic function (using debug, or mtrace in the debug package)?

As an example, I want to debug cenreg in the NADA package, specifically the method that takes a formula input.

You can retrieve the method details like this:

```
library(NADA)
getMethod("cenreg", c("formula", "missing", "missing"))

function (obs, censored, groups, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (obs, censored, groups, dist, conf.int = 0.95, 
        ...) 
    {
        dist = ifelse(missing(dist), "lognormal", dist)

...
}
```

The problem is that cenreg itself looks like this:

```
body(cenreg)
# standardGeneric("cenreg")
```

I don't know how to step through the underlying method, rather than the generic wrapper.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My first two suggestions are pretty basic: (1) wrap your function call in a `try()` (that frequently provides more information with S4 classes) and (2) call `traceback()` after the error is thrown (that can sometimes give hints to where the problem is really occuring).

Calling `debug()` won't help in this scenario, so you need to use `trace` or `browser`.  From the debug help page:

```
"In order to debug S4 methods (see Methods), you need to use trace, typically 
calling browser, e.g., as "
  trace("plot", browser, exit=browser, signature = c("track", "missing"))
```

S4 classes can be hard to work with; one example of this is the comment in [the `debug` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/debug/index.html) documentation (regarding the usage of `mtrace()` with S4 classes):

```
"I have no plans to write S4 methods, and hope not to have to
debug other people’s!"
```

A [similar question was asked recently on R-Help](http://old.nabble.com/debugging-S4-methods-td25697205.html).  The recommendation from Duncan Murdoch:

```
"You can insert a call to browser() if you want to modify the source.  If
you'd rather not do that, you can use trace() to set a breakpoint in it.
The new setBreakpoint() function in R 2.10.0 will also work, if you
install the package from source with the R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE=yes
environment variable set.  It allows you to set a breakpoint at a
particular line number in the source code."
```

I've never done this before myself (and it requires R 2.10.0), but you might try installing from source with `R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE=yes`.

Incidentally, you can use the [CRAN mirror of NADA](https://github.com/cran/NADA) in github to browse the source.

Comment: A very thorough answer; thank you.  I've opted for trace("cenreg", exit=recover), which has done the trick nicely.

Comment: Quoting the [release notes](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) of R 3.4.0,  a `signature` argument was added to `debug()`, `debugonce()`, `undebug()` and `isdebugged()` for more conveniently debugging S3 and S4 methods. (Based on a patch by Gabe Becker.)

Comment: Please down-vote this answer and up-vote the answer by Gabe Becker because these days `debug("plot", signature = c("track", "missing"))` does indeed work.

Answer (score 20):

For a long time this was a standard annoyance point for S4 method debugging. As pointed out by Charles Plessy, I worked with  Michael Lawrence to add a number of features to R that are intended to make this easier.

`debug`, `debugonce`, `undebug` and `isdebugged` all now take a signature argument  suitable for specifying  s4 methods. Furthermore, debugging S4 methods this way bypasses the weird implementation detail that you previously had to deal with by hand by `browser`ing into the method via `trace`, stepping through the `.local` definition, debugging that, then continuing.

In addition, I added `debugcall`, which you give an actual, full call that you would want to invoke.  Doing so sets debugging on the *first closure which will be invoked when evaluating that call that is not an S3 or S4 standard generic*. So if you are calling a non-generic, that will just be the top level function being called, but if it is a standard S3 or S4 generic, the first *method* that will be hit is debugged *instead of the generic*. A "standard S3 generic" is defined as a function  where the first top-level (ignoring curly braces) call in the body is a call to UseMethod.

Note we went back and forth on the design of this but at the end of the day settled on `debugcall` **not** actually executing the function call being debugged, but it returns the call expression which you can pass it to `eval` if desired, as illustrated in `?debugcall`.