# Debugging unexpected S4 method dispatch

Tags: r, bioconductor, r-s4

I am trying to pass an S4 object (sparse matrix of class `dgCMatrix` from the `Matrix` package) to a function in another package ([`Wrench`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Wrench.html)). I am getting some very strange behavior that I am struggling to understand. I suspect it has something to do with S3/S4 method dispatch in R, a subject which I don't really understand.

Example setup:

```r
library(Matrix)
library(Wrench)

M <- Matrix(10 + 1:28, 4, 7)
M[, c(2,4:6)] <- 0
sM <- as(M, "sparseMatrix")
print(sM)
# 4 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                     
# [1,] 11 . 19 . . . 35
# [2,] 12 . 20 . . . 36
# [3,] 13 . 21 . . . 37
# [4,] 14 . 22 . . . 38

print(rowSums(sM))
# [1] 65 68 71 74
```

Next, I call the function, `Wrench::wrench` to do my analysis:

```r
wrench(sM, colData=c('A','B','A','B','B','A','B'))
# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
#   error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Strange... I set a breakpoint on that line in RStudio, step into `wrench`, it starts like this:

```r
function (mat, condition, etype = "w.marg.mean", ebcf = TRUE, 
  z.adj = FALSE, phi.adj = TRUE, detrend = FALSE, ...) 
{
  mat <- mat[rowSums(mat) > 0, ]
  # ...
```

Step into that first line, into the call to `rowSums(mat)`, and find myself in `base::rowSums`.

```r
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L) 
{
  if (is.data.frame(x)) 
    x <- as.matrix(x)
  if (!is.array(x) || length(dn <- dim(x)) < 2L) 
    stop("'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions")
```

`is.data.frame(x)` is `FALSE`, `is.array(x)` is FALSE, the `stop()` function is invoked and the error originates from within there. OK, so `base::rowSums` doesn't know how to handle the sparse matrix and is raising the error...

**But why is `base::rowSums` being invoked when `rowSums(mat)` is called within `wrench`, whereas `Matrix::rowSums.dgCMatrix` is being invoked and everything is working fine when I call `rowSums(sM)` in the outer scope?**

**More generally, how do I debug this kind of problem, where method dispatch is not happening as expected** (especially within a package that I don't control)?

Other things I have tried:

- I tried using [`debugcall`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708074/debugging-generic-functions-in-r), i.e. `eval(debugcall(rowSums(sM)))` from the outer scope, and it takes me into somewhere in `Matrix` which calls some C code and ultimately the row sums are printed. When I try the same thing with the debugger paused within `Wrench::wrench`, I get an error:

  ```
  Browse[1]> eval(debugcall(rowSums(mat))) 
  Error in .signatureFromCall(func, mcall, env) :    
  trying to get slot "signature" from an object of a basic class ("function") with no slots
  ```
- I have read the [S4 chapter of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html) several times

Comment: I don't have an answer but it might be important that `rowSums` is an implicit generic (see `help("implicitGeneric")`) because package matrix exports methods but not (anymore) a generic for it (see the relevant comment in [the Matrix source code](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/Matrix/NAMESPACE?view=markup&root=matrix)). Might be worth a report to the Matrix maintainer.

Comment: However, if Wrench is supposed to work with sparse matrices, it should import the Matrix package.

Comment: and since it doesn't do so, I don't believe you can expect it to work with Matrix objects at all.

Comment: This is helpful though; I have learned that the libraries Wrench imports affects S4 dispatch within Wrench, and about the additional nightmare that is `implicitGeneric`. That probably explains what is going on here. I'd still like to know what tools I should be using to debug this kind of problem in the future. Is there a function like [`sloop::s3_dispatch`](https://sloop.r-lib.org/reference/s3_dispatch.html) where I can figure out what S4 method (if any) will be dispatched for a given call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NAMESPACE` needs either

```
import(Matrix)
```

or

```r
importFrom("Matrix", ...)
importClassesFrom("Matrix", ...)
importMethodsFrom("Matrix", "[", rowSums, ...)
```

the latter importing only as necessary (a practice that you are encouraged to follow).

As for debugging, note that several enclosures separate the evaluation environment of the function `wrench` from your global environment and rest of the search path:

```
1. the evaluation environment of 'wrench'
2. the 'Wrench' namespace
3. the 'Wrench' imports
4. the 'base' namespace
5. the global environment { and the rest of search() }
```

You can verify that by calling `parent.env` recursively inside of the debugger, like so:

```
> library(Wrench)
> debugonce(wrench)
> wrench()
Browse[2]> e <- environment()
Browse[2]> repeat { print(e); if (identical(e, .GlobalEnv)) break; e <- parent.env(e) }
debug at #1: print(e)
Browse[3]> c
<environment: 0x11e032028>
<environment: namespace:Wrench>
<environment: 0x11e84bf40>
attr(,"name")
[1] "imports:Wrench"
<environment: namespace:base>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
Browse[2]>
```

When you import methods for `rowSums` from **Matrix**, an S4 generic `rowSums` is placed in your package imports.  The generic `rowSums` there is found before the non-generic `rowSums` in the **base** namespace, because your package imports are searched first.  When called, the generic `rowSums` dispatches an appropriate method from the corresponding methods table.  If it does not find one, then it calls the default method, which for `rowSums` is just the non-generic function.

```r
Browse[2]> rowSums
standardGeneric for "rowSums" defined from package "base"

function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1, ...) 
standardGeneric("rowSums")
<bytecode: 0x1182be180>
<environment: 0x1182b78f8>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods(rowSums)  for currently available ones.
Browse[2]> environment(rowSums)$.MTable$CsparseMatrix
Method Definition:

function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1L, sparseResult = FALSE) 
    .Call("CRsparse_rowSums", x, na.rm, FALSE, sparseResult)
    .local(x, na.rm, dims, ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x11b88dd60>
<environment: namespace:Matrix>

Signatures:
        x              
target  "CsparseMatrix"
defined "CsparseMatrix"
Browse[2]> rowSums@default
Method Definition (Class "derivedDefaultMethod"):

function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1, ...) 
base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...)
<environment: 0x118261ff8>

Signatures:
        x    
target  "ANY"
defined "ANY"
```

Importantly, if **Wrench** imports from **Matrix**, then loading **Wrench** automatically loads **Matrix**, so methods for `rowSums` exported by **Matrix** are always available in the methods table for use by functions in **Wrench**.

A subtle aspect of this example is that the `[` operator, unlike `rowSums`, is *internally* S4 generic.  An S4 generic `[` is *not* placed in your package imports when you import methods for `[`, but S4 dispatch works anyway.

So, in theory, you can get away *without* importing methods for `[` from **Matrix**, as long as you import *something* from **Matrix** to ensure that its methods are loaded whenever **Wrench** is loaded.  But that's really just a technical detail; for clarity, *do* use `NAMESPACE` to import all of the methods that your package might need.

Comment: This is full of helpful information, thanks! Your answer pointed me to read the [Environments](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#search-path) chapter of Advanced R, which helped a lot. Also now I know about [`methods::showMethods`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.2/topics/showMethods). I still wish there were a function that would tell me what S4 method would be dispatched for a given call, but this is better than nothing.

Comment: There is: `selectMethod`. In the debugger, start by checking `methods::is(rowSums, "genericFunction")`.  If `TRUE`, then `selectMethod(rowSums, signature = "dgCMatrix")` returns the method that would be dispatched for `rowSums(<dgCMatrix>)`. If `FALSE`, then `rowSums(<dgCMatrix>)` is almost certainly calling the `rowSums` in **base**. You can always verify with `identical(environment(rowSums), .BaseNamespaceEnv)`.